# Why is the number of unread messages in Messages negative?

Tags: messages, bug

Occasionally, and with no apparent correlation with what is going on on other devices where I have Messages enabled, I get a negative count for my unread messages in Messages on OS X:

[image]

What could be causing this, and how can I prevent from happening in the future?

Comment: I can't help with a solution or workaround but this is clearly a bug and you should report it: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: I'm stuck at 1 (positive) unread message, despite having read all messages. Clearly bugs here. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that negative numbers show up when you read a message on another device before you read it on what ever device has the negative number. I had the same thing happen to me. I have a "-1" badge on my Messages icon.